# Count the occurrences comparing other file

Tags: text-processing, files

I have two files:

`F1.txt`:

```
a:erwer|ee
b:eeeee|eee
c:ewrew|erwe
```

and `F2.txt`:

```
a.T1
a.T2
b.T3
C.T7
c.T4
```

I need to check the number of occurrences of the `a`,`b`,`c` keywords by checking F1.txt) from F2.txt.

Expected output in F1.txt:

```
a:erwer|ee:total:2
b:eeeee|eeet:total:1
c:ewrew|erwe:total:2
```

Update o/p in another file:

```
a:2
b:1
c:2
```

Comment: Is this really representative of your data? Do you _always_ have a single letter per line in `F1`? Can any pattern in `F1` be a sub-pattern of another line? Can you have both `a` and `aa`, for example? And in `F2` is it _always_ the case that we have one of the patterns from `F1` as the first string on a line and then a `.`?

Comment: yes, you are correct. F1 has uniq $1 column data (e.g. $1:$2).
F2'$1 is same F1'$1

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I know these may seem like minor details, but it is very important that your example accurately represents your data. My answer is useless now that you have given a more accurate example, which just goes to show how important it is.

Comment: Silently changing the spec is counterproductive. If you need to make an edit, it's helpful to make a note of that.

Comment: sure. apologies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your file isn't too large, you can use awk :

```
awk '
BEGIN{FS=".";OFS=":"}
NR==FNR{a[tolower($0)]=0;next}
{ 
    if(tolower($1) in a){
        a[tolower($1)]++
    }
} 
END{
    for(key in a){
        print key, a[key]
    }
}
' F1.txt F2.txt
```

And in case you want something case sensitive remove the `tolower` function.

---

For your edited question :

```
awk '
BEGIN{FS="[:.]";OFS=":"}
NR==FNR{l[tolower($1)]=$0;cpt[tolower($1)]=0;next}
{
    if(tolower($1) in cpt){
        cpt[tolower($1)]++
    }
}
END{
    for(key in cpt){
        print l[key],"total",cpt[key]
    }
}
' F1.txt F2.txt
```

Comment: can we have sch* and total count in separate file ?

Comment: if my file has more than 2000 rows of data in f2.txt?

Comment: Hello @rose I'm not sure to understand what you are asking for. Try asking a new question instead of here in the comment.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start by treating the `F2.txt` file as a CSV file with the dot as the field separator.  We may turn the 1st field into lowercase, and then count the number of distinct values in the 1st field.  By using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) below, the unique 1st field values and their count are outputted with a `:` as the delimiter, as requested:

```bash
$ mlr --csv --ifs . --ofs : -N put '$1 = tolower($1)' then count -g 1 F2.txt
a:2
b:1
c:2
```

To filter and combine this result with the contents of the `F1.txt`, we use `join`:

```bash
$ mlr --csv --ifs . --ofs : -N put '$1 = tolower($1)' then count -g 1 F2.txt | join -t : F1.txt -
a:erwer|ee:2
b:eeeee|eee:1
c:ewrew|erwe:2
```

Would you want the string `total:` inserted before the number at the end, you may pass this through an extra pipeline stage which adds it with `sed 's/.*:/&total:/'`.

```bash
$ mlr --csv --ifs . --ofs : -N put '$1 = tolower($1)' then count -g 1 F2.txt | join -t : F1.txt - | sed 's/.*:/&total:/'
a:erwer|ee:total:2
b:eeeee|eee:total:1
c:ewrew|erwe:total:2
```

---

A variant using `awk`:

```bash
$ awk -F : 'FNR==NR { split($0,a,"."); count[tolower(a[1])]++; next } $1 in count { printf "%s:total:%s\n", $0, count[$1] }' F2.txt F1.txt
a:erwer|ee:total:2
b:eeeee|eee:total:1
c:ewrew|erwe:total:2
```

The `awk` code:

```c
BEGIN { FS = ":" }

FNR==NR {
    split($0,a,".")
    count[tolower(a[1])]++
    next
}

$1 in count {
    printf "%s:total:%s\n", $0, count[$1]
}
```

---

Just for the heck of it: Showing how one may use Miller's Docker image to run the first command above:

```bash
docker run --rm -i jauderho/miller:latest \
    --csv --ifs . --ofs : -N \
    put '$1 = tolower($1)' then count -g 1 <F2.txt
```

... or even...

```bash
alias mlr='docker run --rm -i jauderho/miller:latest'

mlr --csv --ifs . --ofs : -N put '$1 = tolower($1)' then count -g 1 <F2.txt
```

Comment: mlr is unavailable

Comment: @rose ... until it's installed. As shown [here](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-miller/), Miller may also be used as a Docker image.

Answer (score 0):

Perl would be a good fit here, although it could be done in awk or as @terdon shows with a pipeline of various tools (but note the caveats about substrings in that solution).

Here's some sample input.:

file1

```
a
b
c
d
```

file2

```
a.T1
a.T2
b.T3
C.T7
c.T4
```

and a sample run:

```
% perl count.pl file1 file2
a:2
b:1
c:2
d:0
```

Here's a relatively structured version in Perl. It uses the language's "magic readline" feature in place of more explicit file handling. It has no error handling but what the runtime provides automatically. It uses "slurp mode" reading the file for the keys, so for that file a warning about its size vs memory may be worthwhile, but it's doubtful your file of keys to find will be terribly large. It does loop properly over `file2` line by line without pulling it all into memory so that one can be arbitrarily large. It uses a regex match, so anything that's before a final '.' then 'T' then a single digit can be matched from `file1`.

```
#!perl
use warnings;
use strict;

sub get_keys {
 local $/ = undef;
 return { map { lc $_ => 0 } split /\n/, <> };
}

sub count {
 my $m = shift;
 while (<>) {
  if ( m/(.*)\.T\d/ ) {
   $m->{lc $1}++ if exists $m->{lc $1}
  }
 }
 return $m;
}

sub output {
 my $m = shift;
 for my $k ( sort keys %$m ) {
  printf "%s:%d\n", $k, $m->{$k};
 }
 return;
}

output count get_keys;
```

Here's a shorter, more one-off type version still in Perl, with the same core logic.

```
#!perl
use warnings;
use strict;

undef $/;
my %map = map { lc $_ => 0 } split /\n/, <>;

$/ = "\n";
while (<>) {
 if ( m/(.*)\.T\d/ ) {
  $map{lc $1}++ if exists $map{lc $1}
 }
}

for my $k ( sort keys %map ) {
  printf "%s:%d\n", $k, $map{$k};
}
```

If you want a short command-line version that does the same thing but is still not too hard to read, here's that second version adapted to that.

```
% perl -e '
undef $/;
%m = map { lc $_ => 0 } split /\n/, <>;
$/ = "\n";
while (<>) { if ( /(.*)\.T\d/ ) { $m{lc $1}++ } }
for $k ( sort keys %m ) { printf "%s:%d\n", $k, $m{$k}; }
' file1 file2
a:2
b:1
c:2
d:0
```

Or using auto-looping over input like awk with a BEGIN and END block:

```
% perl -ne '
BEGIN {
 undef $/;
 %m = map { lc $_ => 0 } split /\n/, <>;
 $/ = "\n";
}
if ( /(.*)\.T\d/ ) { $m{lc $1}++ }
END {
 for $k ( sort keys %m ) { printf "%s:%d\n", $k, $m{$k}; }
}
' file1 file2
a:2
b:1
c:2
d:0
```

Note all the code samples in this answer are the same program. They all produce the same output from the same inputs. They're not even substantially rewritten. It's the same logic in the same language with pretty minor adjustments.

One axis along which you should evaluate a solution is how easily you can come back to it later for maintenance. If this was a simple tool that only ever did this one thing and I needed to run it repeatedly but suspected I'd never need to grow the code into something else, I'd probably use the second version or something close to it. If this was part of a much bigger program, I'd start with the first one and probably add more explicit file handling like `open`, `close`, and error handling for those.

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP has changed the Sample Input files. I tried your first code example and it returned zero instances (counts) of each `a`, `b`, and `c`.